# Chrome custom tabs classes not found in code

Tags: android, android-support-library, chrome-custom-tabs

Today was the first time I was trying to setup chrome tabs in an Android project. I included the required compile:

compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.1'

No gradle errors / build errors afterwards but in code the com.android.support.customtabs namespace was not available.. I already tried changing the version to 23.0.1 or the newer 23.1.0 but all changes had the same result. I then looked at my sdk->android folders to see if the customtabs library was actually being downloaded and it was. All the other support namespaces that I'm using are working fine.. Any clue on what could be going wrong here?

Comment: The CustomTabs classes are inside the "android.support.customtabs" package. Eg: "android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent". I just added the library to an existing project and it worked. If it's still impossible to find the classes, maybe doing a "File > Invalidade Caches / Restart" on Android Studio?

Comment: Thanks @andreban, your solution worked in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working again => just clean / rebuild didn't work so what I had to do to solve it:

=> goto SDK manager => delete the (complete) android support library and afterwards reinstall the package.

This fixed the problem so I could not check if @andreban's "file->invalidate caches" also fixes the problem.